# How to change activation's of a layer using lambda function during training

Tags: machine-learning, lambda, keras

I am new to keras and trying to modify the outputs of a layer during training. I want to write a function that takes the layer outputs and return the modeified outputs to the next layer during learning. I have tried using lambda functions but not really got hold of it.

```
def fun(x):
  a = min(x)
  y = np.round(x*(2**a))
return y

layer_1 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(input)
layer_2 = Dense(12, activation='relu')(layer_1)
lambda_layer = Lambda(fun, output_shape=(12,))(layer_2)
layer_3 = dense(32, activation='relu')(lambda_layer)
```

how can I get the layer outputs and modify them before passing it to next layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a lambda function is the right approach for your problem. However, keep in mind that the lambda function will be part of your computational graph and during training gradients have to be computed for the whole graph.

For example, you should not use the `min()` function as you did but rather use functions which are part of [Keras Backend](https://keras.io/backend/). Replacing all operations by their keras backend equivalent results in:

```py
import keras.backend as K

def fun(x):
    a = K.min(x)
    y = K.round(K.dot(x, (K.pow(2, a))))
    return y
```

Your final model (and so all `Lambda` layers) should only contain native Keras functions, in order to safely perform all calculations during training.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, it cleared most of my doubts. Also I am not able to understand how the outputs of a layer are passed to lambda and how it handles the return values. Can you please help me undestand this?

Comment: I dont quite get your question. The lambda layer is handled like any other layer in your model. As you did you can integrate it using the functional or also the sequential keras api.

Answer (score 0):

This fails because you are using non-native operations (like `np.round`) inside a `Lambda` function, which expects `keras` operations

Examine the [`keras.backend`](https://keras.io/backend/) docs, and take the functions you want to use from there.

So your function should look something like this

```py
from keras import backend as K

def fun(x):
    a = K.min(x, axis=-1)  # Specify the axis you need!
    y = K.round(x*(2**a))

    return y
```